# Trying to dectect when WKWebKit start loading video, to stop animation

Tags: swift, uiwebview, wkwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

I conformed to "WKNavigationDelegate" and according to the document I am using 
these methods, but it seems like they're not getting call. I am not getting any result.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    stopAnimating()

    print("didStart Video is loading...")
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didCommit navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    stopAnimating()

    print("Video is loading...")
}
```

Complete Code, anyhelp in the right direction would help, Thanks!

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    NVActivityIndicatorView.DEFAULT_BLOCKER_SIZE = CGSize(width: 35, height: 35)
    startAnimating(message:"Loading...", type: .lineScale, color: .lightGray)

    guard let url = holdUrl else {return}

    if let url = URL(string:url) {
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        myWebView.load(request)
        myWebView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding "myWebView.navigationDelegate = self" fixed my problem...